# Markup langage to easily write technical texts

Tags: markup-languages

I'm looking for a syntax that allows me to write in a simple way (not like in LaTeX or HTML) documents with technical elements (chess boards, music scores, tables ...) in addition to the usual bold, italic, underlined ...

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be Markdown. You can include png files in it too.
Its syntax is easy to use and very well documented.

Comment: I know markdown very well but the problem with inserting images is that they are not easily editable.